# С какой буквы писать государственная?

Tags: прописная-строчная

Начальнику государственной службы

Comment: Что за служба такая? Есть комитеты, департаменты, управления, агентства, министерства. А "государственная служба" это профессиональная деятельность, какой у нее может быть начальник?

Comment: Возможно, название службы опущено. Вопрос требует доработки.

Answer (score 1):

Если слово "государственная" является первым словом в официальном названии службы, тогда с прописной. Например: "Государственная противопожарная служба РФ". Но официальное название службы тогда нужно писать полностью (или использовать общепринятое сокращение). Нельзя писать: "начальнику Государственной службы РФ по борьбе с пожарами".

Во всех других случаях, вероятно, будет писаться со строчной. Например: "Совет по вопросам государственной службы при Президенте РФ".